# How does one use the "New FaceTime" window on macOS version of FaceTime?

Tags: macos, facetime, call, wifi-calling

I am in the USA.
I am trying to **FaceTime** someone who lives abroad from a shared Mac computer.
My contacts are not synced with this computer.

When I click the "**New FaceTime**" window, I am prompter to `Enter a name, email, or number`

However, neither a name, number or email that I have tried entering made the FaceTime button active.

**Was it because FaceTime cannot find the person? Can you FaceTime someone abroad from a MacOS?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name: If you don't have your Contacts, then no names will return results. For people who do have Contacts then it just serves as shortcuts to the other options.

Number: Enter the phone number, and press enter (in the search box). If it's a registered number, it will turn blue and the call button will become active. If it's not a registered number, it will turn green and the button will become an option to text a FaceTime link

Email: Enter the email, and press enter (in the search box). If it's a registered email, it will turn blue and the call button will become active. It's it's not a registered number then it will not allow you to proceed.

If you can't figure out how to call them, then use the Create Link button instead and send them the link. You CAN call anyone with FaceTime, region does not matter unless they are in the few areas of the world that do not permit FaceTime to operate.

Comment: Thanks. I think the key was to press "Enter" after typing the number. What do you mean with "registered number" - someone whose phone number is associated to an Apple account?

Comment: Yes - registered with Apple to receive FaceTime calls. I'm not sure it needs to be attached to an account necessarily, but I may be wrong. Either way, the recipient would see the number as available to receive FaceTime calls from in Settings if it's been set up properly